# Passing Anonymous types as parameters to the functions

Tags: .net, anonymous-types

I need to pass to a function an object that is an anonymous type.

The thing I expect that the object contains some properties, say Name(string) and Rang(BO).

Say, I have a query like

```
  Dim query = From city In _container.Cities
               From street In city.Streets
               Select Name = street.Name, Rang = street.Rang
               Distinct
```

Now, I would like to pass each element of this query to a function.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use a nominal type? It would make things *way* easier, and likely clearer as well.

Comment: @dlev: I have a lot of query like this, should I build for each query an object?

Comment: It depends on your model, but more often you'd have nominal types for each entity, and just pass those around. Since you're using VB, JaredPar's answer should be fine as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible.

You can use cast by example. Here's a sample:

```
class CastByExample {
    public T Cast<T>(T t, object toCast) {
        return (T)toCast;
    }

    public void M(object o) {
        var y = Cast(new { Name = "Name", Range = 0 }, o);
        Console.WriteLine(y.Name);
    }

    public void Test() {
        var x = new { Name = "John Doe", Range = 17 };
        M(x);
    }
}
```

You can also use reflection.

But really, how is jumping through these hoops easier than just writing a concrete non-anonymous type?

Comment: what should be the method signature then?

Comment: What do you expect to cast to?

Comment: @serhio: It should take an instance of `object`.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Please see my example.

Comment: The user asked the question in VB.Net and you provided a C# answer.

Comment: @JaredPar: Is OK C# answer, the question is not specific to VB.NET

Comment: @JaredPar: It's tagged .NET, not VB.NET.

Comment: This example has some serious flaws - It will work, in the simplest of cases.  However, it breaks down if you refactor later, and move a method into a different library, for example, as the cast will then fail... It's really not a solution, as much as a horrible hack that gets around this problem in a way that was never intended to be used....

Comment: @Reed Copsey: "But really, how is jumping through these hoops easier than just writing a concrete non-anonymous type?"

Comment: @Jason: I know - but the crux of your answer was that you could do this - I wanted to point out that it works, but only in a limited scenario - it's not a consistent way to handle it, even if you like the hoops.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: The question was asking if it's possible so of course my answer was whether or not it could be done. I don't disagree with the points you're drawing though. The *right* way to handle this is a nominal type. Period.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, no.  From MSDN :

"You cannot declare a field, a property, an event, or the return type of a method as having an anonymous type. Similarly, you cannot declare a formal parameter of a method, property, constructor, or indexer as having an anonymous type."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

There isn't a good way (meaning simple) to pass an anonymous type between methods.  I would create a helper class instead.

Having said that, you might also be interested in Jon Skeet's article on anonymous types leaving the method scope:

http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance/

Comment: @serhio: The only thing that matters is how many functions you have - not how many queries...

Comment: @Reed Copsey OK, I have a lot of functions, now, should I build for each function an object?

Comment: @serhio: I'd, personally, build an object for each business object in your domain, so that you're passing around meaningful things.  You should be able to reuse types throughout your functions (or define the functions on the types themselves, which is even better...)

Comment: yeah, from the Jon Skeet article I see the Jason's answer )

Comment: The link is dead on the Jon Skeet article.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to state the type of an anonymous object in VB.Net.  However if you're comfortable with `Option Strict Off` then you can use late binding.  Just have the target method accept the parameter of type `Object`

```vb
Public Sub UseAnonymousObject(ByVal p as Object)
  Console.WriteLine(p.Name)
  Console.WriteLine(p.Rang)
End Sub

...

For Each current in query 
  UseAnonymousObject(current)
Next
```

Comment: what if I am not comfortable with Option Strict Off?

Comment: @serhio without `Option Strict Off` then you either need to do a casting trick or better just go ahead and define a simple type which contains the properties you want and use that instead

Comment: in my case "define a simple type" => "define some sample types" (a lot of)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked too much into them, and I may be missing the point of your question, but if you're on the .Net 4 framework, you could use [Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) instead of anonymous types.   They seem to lose the explicit property naming that is nice w/ Anonymous types, but they do have an advantage in that they can be passed to and from methods.

The other draw-back, though, is that the method signature does still need to be defined with the proper Tuple definition.  So, in most cases, I'm not sure that it buys you too much over just using non-anonymous types, because what it offers in flexbility, it hinders in terms meaningful argument communication.

So I would not recommend them for this type of use at any sort of broad-level interface.  (e.g. publicly exposed methods with argument types like Tuple seem much better suited to well-defined type definitions over the overly-vague Tuple arguments)   They can be handy, though, and well-suited I think, for private methods that support one-off, ad-hoc type objects.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but how about using dynamics?

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> SubMethod(...)
{
    ....
    return (IEnumerable<dynamic>) (from .... select new{Property1 = v1,...})
}

void Method()
{
    var q = SubMethod().FirstOrDefault();  //or whatever
    var j = q.Property1;
    ...
}
```